# Disable html error reporting on nginx

Tags: nginx, http

Is it possible to completly remove the html erroring reporting in nginx

for instance, when I have a 403 error nginx serves the following :

```
<html>
<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

I m using nginx for serving for a webservice and I don't need this error reporting.
Just the http response code and no output is fine for me

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/189912

Comment: not a XY problem, I m asking for a simple configuration option in nginx that seems to be missing. the problem would have been solved with technologies like node.js , which gives you full control on your http response , but seems tricky with nginx.

Answer (score 0):

That's possible with a dirty trick, for a specific block. Assuming you don't have a regex with a capture group in your location block :

```
return 403 "$1";
```

Edit: need some clarification on your architecture.

Comment: because the response is read by a game , not a browser, and you dont need more than the http status code in case the request fail

Comment: @N-AccessDev why is nginx directly returning 403 codes to your application ? Don't you use it as a reverse proxy ?

Comment: I use it with PHP + PHP-FPM. nginx is not used as a reserve proxy.

Comment: @N-AccessDev Aha, so it IS an XY problem. And besides, you can always send empty response bodies directly from PHP.

Comment: for 403 errors, they are managed via NGINX location rules. for 50x errors, they occurs when the server loads too much , in these cases the PHP script is rarely cauled.